# Why is my configuration test class not working?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, javabeans

I am trying to write unit test using junit for my service configuration class. I have existing code that works in other module, but it doesn't work on this module for some reason and I cannot figure this out. Here is my code:

ServiceConfig class:

```
package config.service;

import service.Service;
import service.ServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Bean
    public Service service() {
        return new serviceImpl();
    }
}
```

Service interface:

```
package service;

public interface Service {

    void search() throws Exception;
}
```

ServiceImpl class:

```
package service;

public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    @Override
    public void search() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

ServiceConfigTest class:

```
package config.service;

import service.Service;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ServiceConfig.class })
public class ServiceConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void service() {
        assertNotNull(service);
    }
}
```

and here is the Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ServiceConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'Service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.nuance.powershare.dispatchreporter.service.Service' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I don't have too much experience with spring and configuration classes. However, this seems legit to me, I basically followed the code that was already working in other module. My manager also cannot find what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above exception is caused, when we did not create a bean of the type it will raise an exception  "Error creating bean with name 'className'.

I tried the same code it's working for me. However, you don't need to create Service Config to create a bean of ServiceImpl just annotate ServiceImpl with @Service and you can test it subsequently.

```
 @Service
 public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

 @Override
 public void search() throws Exception {

   }
}
```

and avoid using the predefined names(ex: Service) for the class name.

Comment: I had to change the name of classes for security reason. So you were able to build without any issue with exact my code? My manager is also suspecting my project structure issue..

Comment: yes, I run code its working for me.  @Autowired private Service service; in configure class has no effect. because configure class is used to create beans, instead you already using it without creating it.

Comment: yeah I actually deleted whole branch and re-write the code and it worked. Still not sure what is wrong but i will take it :)